# jQuery ColorPicker plugin

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I am using the jQuery Color Picker plugin.

The colorSelector element allows the user to pick the colour. When the colour is selected I would like to to change the #previewFrame div background colour to the selected hex.

I am having problems achieving this. The #previewFrame colour does not change but the #colorSelector background colour does.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
            color: '#0000ff',
            onShow: function (colpkr) {
                $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                return false;
            },
            onHide: function (colpkr) {
                $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                return false;
            },
            onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                $('#colorSelector div').css('background-color', '#' + hex);
                $('#previewFrame div').css('background-color', '#' + hex);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Here are the DIVs.

```
<div id="previewFrame" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #000;">
    <div style="background-color: #0000ff"></div>
</div>
<div id="colorSelector">
    <div style="background-color: #0000ff"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it wont work unless you set height/width of the internal div.

Comment: I've applied height and width but still does not work.

Comment: Here is my example http://jainsworth.co.uk/